# Función para convertir una lista en un string que repita los caracteres según el valor original

Tags: python

Tengo una lista:

```
list =  [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Busco una función eficiente para obtener como output un string de caracteres numéricos en que cada caracter aparezca repetido tantas veces como su valor original en la lista. Es decir:

```
string = "122333444455555"
```

El primer paso que he dado ha sido convertir la lista en string:

```
l = "".join(str(x) for x in list)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Siguiendo con tu idea simplemente multiplica cada elemeto por si mismo dentro del generador:

```
l = [1, 2 ,3 , 4, 5]
l = "".join(str(x)*x for x in l)
print(l)
```

**Salida:**

> '122333444455555'

**Nota:** nunca llames a tu variable `list`, es una palabra reservada en Python y con eso la sobreescribes. Usa `list_` o cualquier otra cosa.